# Redefine/overload type casting

Tags: java, casting

Every object has a toString method inherited from the Object class it extends, which can be overloaded. IS there a way to do a similar thing with objects? Here is what I want to do: 
int a=n+1; where n is actually an object, but when used as an int has a specific value (eg. specified in the constructor).

Comment: No, this kind of thing can be accomplished in C++ but Java doesn't allow operator overloading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called operator overloading. You cannot do it in Java. And it is disallowed by design as far as I'm aware. I guess you're coming from C++ or C#, where this is possible.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use objects with arithmetic operators. In java these operators cannot be overloaded and adding an object to a number makes little sense.

Sidenote: overriding is not the same as overloading.