# Cast from object to HashSet<String>

Tags: java, object, hashset

```
 private void init_Persistent_Object() throws Throwable {
    PersistentObject myPO = new PersistentObject();
    java.util.HashSet<String> myMap = new java.util.HashSet<String>();
    myPO.init("HPOReference", myMap); // Init class



private void check_Persistant_Obj() throws Throwable {
    PersistentObject myPO = new PersistentObject();


    java.util.HashSet<String> myName1 = null;



myName1 = (java.util.HashSet<String>)myPO.get("HPOReference"); //update class.
```

Apparently I can't cast object to hashSet but I'm not quite sure how I should solve this? Is it possible to add it to an array and then put the array in the HashSet somehow? Could I perhaps get some help on how this should be done if it is the right way to go. I appreciate any guidance I can get :) Thanks in advance!

Edit: the last line in the code is the one that fails on me, incase it was unclear.

Comment: Why does it fail? Do you get a `ClassCastException`? What is the exact error message? The error message tells you what type the actual object is.

Comment: Can you add stacktrace

Comment: We would probably need to see the implementation of the get() method...  tempted to close as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20412245/1339987.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are talking about @djechlin. The get method is implemented in the init class.

Comment: You have not posted the implementation, or declaration, of any `get` function.

Comment: A HashSet is internally a HashMap with null values. Maybe that fact confuses the serializer. Can you try `new HashSet(myPO.get())` ?

Comment: Hey Guillaume, It didn't work.

Comment: If you dont add stacktrace it will be just guessing game.

Comment: I will add stacktrace tomorrow. However the compiler stops at the last line of the code with the error: Can not cast Hashmap to HashSet.